# How to run grep with while loop in shell script?

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm trying to make shell script that counts 9 letters words consisted of A, G, C, T in B.txt.

First,
9bp_cases.txt contains

```
AAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAG
AAAAAAAAC
AAAAAAAAT
AAAAAAAGA
AAAAAAAGG
AAAAAAAGC
...
```

```
//#!/bin/bash

file=/Dataset/4.synTF/2.Sequence/9bp_cases.txt

# CSV 파일이 존재하지 않으면 종료

if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "CSV 파일이 존재하지 않습니다: $file" >&2
    exit 1 
fi

cat 9bp_cases.txt | while read line;
do
    echo $line 
    grep -i -o $line B.txt | wc -w
done
```

The result is like this:

```
//AAAAAAAAA
0
AAAAAAAAG
0
AAAAAAAAC
0
AAAAAAAAT
0
AAAAAAAGA
0
```

None of the words is counted correctly.
However, when I run the simple code, it returns result well.

```
grep -i -o AAAAAAAA B.txt | wc -w
33410
```

I guess $line after grep is not recognized by the command grep.
Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Put an `echo` before the line to see what the shell makes of this. Also, your `AAAAAAAAA` seems to be `//AAAAAAAAA` from the output, so there is something wrong already.

Comment: Also, make sure your `9bp_cases.txt` file is a plain unix textfile, ie. only has `\n` as the line separator, and that the lines have no trailing whitespace.

Comment: Another approach would be starting with `grep -Eo "[ACGT]{9}" B.txt | sort | uniq -c`.
When this works, compare with `9bp_cases.txt`, cf `grep -f 9bp_cases.txt <(grep -Eo "[ACGT]{9}" B.txt | sort | uniq -c)`.

Comment: I don't understand from your problem description, which result you would expect in your example.